# to find the spectral measure $E : M_{\phi} \to B(H)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Consider $[0,1] $ with $\mu$ Lebsgue measure on $[0,1]$ .Let  $H = L^2([0,1], \mu)$. For $\phi \in L^{\infty}([0,1],\mu)$.

Define $M_{\phi} \in B(L^2([0,1], \mu))$ by $M_{\phi}(f) = \phi f, \ f\in L^2([0,1], \mu)$ .

I have shown that $\sigma(M_{\phi}) = \text{ess range}  \ \phi$.

Now to find the spectral measure $E : M_{\phi} \to B(H)$ of $M_{\phi}$.

Required Hints to do the problem.

Comment: Do you mean $\Omega=[0,1]$?

Comment: **Hint.** Try the case $\phi(x)=x$ and the case, when $\phi(x)$ has finitely many values.

Comment: The hint I can give is that this question is already answered on this site.

Comment: @MartinArgerami is this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256330/compute-spectral-projection-valued-measures-explicitly?rq=1

Comment: That would be a particular case. I was thinking about [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98480/spectral-measure-of-the-multiplication-operator/98631#98631).